# How can I create a bulleted list using Material UI components?

Tags: material-ui

How can I create a bulleted list using MUI components? I have tried adding `sx={{listStyleType:'disc'}}` to the List component, but no luck. Here is my code :

```html
    <List sx={{ listStyleType: 'disc' }}>
      <ListSubheader sx={{
        fontWeight: 700, lineHeight: '24px', fontSize: '16px', color: 'black'
      }}
      >
        Search Help
      </ListSubheader>
      <ListItem>Double check your spelling</ListItem>
      <ListItem>Your search may have been removed or is not yet in the system</ListItem>
    </List>
```

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I figured it out, needs to be

```
<List sx={{ listStyleType: 'disc' }}>
  <ListItem sx={{ display: 'list-item' }}>
</List>
```

Comment: For this solution to work it has to be used in combination with `<List sx={{ listStyleType: disc', pl: 4 }}></List>`

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
<List
sx = {{
 listStyleType: 'disc',
 pl: 2,
 '& .MuiListItem-root': {
  display: 'list-item',
 },
}}>
 <ListItem>
 ...
 </ListItem>
</List>
```

or

```
<List
sx = {{
 listStyleType: 'disc',
 pl: 2,
}}
</List>
<ListItem
sx = {{
 display: 'list-item',
}}>
 ...
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot, worked for me.

```
<List
   sx={{
        listStyleType: 'disc',
        listStylePosition: 'inside'
      }}
    >
    <ListItem sx={{ display: 'list-item' }}>
       Incoming Bullet
    </ListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

<ListItem style={{ display: 'list-item' }}>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

None of those worked for me for some reason so i had to use Material UI Icons

`<ListItem> <ListItemIcon> < MUIIcon /> </ListItemIcon> <ListItemText primary="" /> </ListItem>`

Answer (score 0):

I successfully did it by using this technique:

```
<ListItem
    sx={{
       padding: 0,
       textAlign: "center",
       listStyleType: "disc",
       display: "list-item",
    }}
></ListItem>
```

If you want the disc to be inside the element. You can also add `listStylePosition: "inside"`.
You can have a look at MDN web docs for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-listitem

Hope this help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sol:
<ListItem sx={{ display: 'list-item' }}> my list</ListItem>
```

use disable padding property  if list  contain lot of padding

```
<ListItem  disablepadding sx={{ display: 'list-item' }}> my list</ListItem>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?